# Can matplotlib change time range dynamicly in stock K line?

Tags: matplotlib

I want to plot a stock K line with matplotlib. I want to change the time range selection dynamicly in my plot like in the attached picture. How can I achieve this?
[image]

Comment: Sound like the span selector https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/widgets/span_selector.html